# App is crashing after setting visibility of a button

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Before implementing set visibility code segement, my app was working perfectly fine but after adding it, it's keep crashing

```
val inputMessage = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputField)
val displayMes = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.displayy)
val submitBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.afterDisplay)
val viewOffers = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnOffers)
submitBtn.setOnClickListener{
    val finalMessage: String = inputMessage.text.toString()
    if(finalMessage == ""){
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Please enter any message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    else{
        displayMes.text = finalMessage
        inputMessage.text.clear()
        viewOffers.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```

XML Code for "View Offer" Button

```
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="#9C27B0"
    android:text="View Offers"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:cornerRadius="23dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.864"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.929"
```

Comment: Please also add error log

Comment: Please add your xml code. Maybe you have not defined the viewOffers in the xml

Comment: @AshutoshOjha shared

Comment: You are using id     android:id="@+id/button" in xml for viewOffer but in code you are calling
val viewOffers = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnOffers). Change button to btnOffers in xml or btnOffers to button in code

Answer (score 0):

Your id in your XML is not the same, instead of this

```
android:id="@+id/button"
```

your should name it

```
android:id="@+id/btnOffers"
```